# ClaimTypes.PrimarySid missing from Identity when testing, but only on some environments

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, azure-devops, claims-based-identity

I have a unit test that has been passing for all local devleoper environments, and our local build server for about 2 years with no problems.

I am now moving the project to another build - visual studio tfs online with both hosted and local build agents. The test only fails when the build is run through TFS online, and fails whether I am using the hosted or private build agent. The private build agent is registered as a service running under a local Windows account.

I might possibly understand it failing on the hosted server (perhaps it's not using a Windows login), but since it also fails on the private build agent, I'm a bit mystified.

```
var incomingIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);

incomingIdentity.AddClaim(
   new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
   ((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity)
    .FindAll(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid)
    .Single() //Exception: Sequence contains no elements
    .Value)
);
```

Why is `ClaimType.PrimarySid` missing from the incoming thread identity?

Comment: Based on my test (output all Claims' type) with MSTest.exe, VSTest.Console.exe, TFS and VSTS private build agent with service or interactive mode, it just contain http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name. (Run test in Visual Studio works fine) What's the result if you run test through MSTest or VSTest.Console.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below in the begin to clarify which PrincipalPolicy to use should fix your issue:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
```